# Capybara RSpec with CSS and JS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, rspec-rails

- rails (5.1.4)
- rspec-rails (3.7.2)
- capybara (2.16.1)

I'm trying to create a RSpec Rails 3.7 System spec as in https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-7/docs/system-specs/system-spec .

Here my simple spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "testing system", type: :system do

  it "tests the spec" do

    visit root_path

    click_link 'Home'

    save_and_open_page

  end
```

The problem is that Capybara does render neither CSS content nor JS content after `save_and_open_page` call (in the browser) - just a plain HTML. The header inside this HTML-file contains some links

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application-ea5a1efcc44a908543519edabe00e74132151ebedeef3c1601921690d9162b5e.css" data-turbolinks-track="reload" />
  <script src="/assets/application-ff63e43aef379fef744a00f21a8aadf96dc2ae8e612f8e7974b231f946569691.js" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
```

but they reference some empty files.

Is there some way to fix it?

I tried some recipes, but still no luck. I tried to precompile the assets, to move "capybara.html" into the "public" folder, but no effect.

Comment: Have you tried `rake assets:clobber` before `rake assets:precompile` to ensure you have a completely clean set of assets?

Comment: Yes. It is a brand new demo project.

Comment: My concern is that your link tags reference empty files. `rake assets:clobber` will clear the assets that are in place, before attempting the precompile. Then, the precompile should return the list of files generated. Plus the link tag should have href attributes pointing to the new js and css files. It might be useful to include the few lines from your layout.html.erb file that shows the page <head> and link tags.

Answer (score 2):

Modifying `stylesheet_link_tag` is not a good solution, a much better  solution is to specify `Capybara.asset_host` which will add a `<base>` tag to any saved pages. Generally this would be set to something like

```
Capybara.asset_host = "http://localhost:3000/"
```

which would then load the JS/CSS assets from your dev server which would have access to the test mode compiled assets in the public subdirectory.  Note: that none of this means the page will actually be functional since JS requests will still fail, DB records won't exist anymore, etc. Also, since it saves element attributes (not properties) a checkbox you just checked will probably not be checked in the saved page. However it will give you a generally styled page you can inspect the structure of. If all you're looking for is a current image of the page you should be using the `save_screenshot`/`save_and_open_screenshot` functionality provided by most of Capybaras drivers instead.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and it works. I just put `Capybara.asset_host = "http://localhost:3000/"` inside `spec\rails_helper.rb` and that's it. This solution is really better.

Comment: @prograils You're welcome, please mark this answer as accepted (the checkmark), if it's the best answer, so your question gets marked as answered

Comment: I'm sorry, but your solution suddenly stopped working somewhy. I don't understand what did I change. Anyway how can it work - `http://localhost:3000/` could ONLY work if a server is running which is not after I call `save_and_open_page`, right? Even setting `Capybara.asset_hos`t as `"file://#{::Rails.root}/public"` doesn't help.

Comment: @prograils As I stated in my answer, it would load them from your dev server instance (as opposed to the test server instance) which most people normally leave running most of the time (when using `rails s` dev defaults to port 3000).  If using pow or puma-dev, instead of manually running `rails s` all the time, your dev server instance might be running on  `<app_name>.dev` or `<app_name>.test` etc so set Capybara.asset_host to that instead (Capybara.app_host = 'http://<app_name>.test/').

Comment: So you solution is not universal since it depends on the dev server running. Besides I am personally just beginning to learn Rails testing so I don't know yet this technique to "keep the dev server running". Maybe you mean Spork or Zeus but I didn't yet touch them.

Comment: @prograils Nothing is "universal" - `save_and_open_page` is to help in  debugging your page to figure out why tests aren't working.  For most people that means they're developing the app and in one shell they have the dev server instance running continuously (by running `rails s` or via pow/puma-dev etc.)

Answer (score 0):

It has to do something with your assets.
Clear cache and run rake `assets:clobber` and rake `assets:precompile`
Still no luck, then check if Capybara is configured correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Check **app/views/layouts/application.html.erb** has the correct Rails tags for stylesheets and javascripts. Something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My App</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
```

On the command line, run:

```
rake assets:clobber
rake assets:precompile
```

Ensure that **public/assets/** include:

```
.sprockets-manifest-<xyz>.json
application-<abc>.js
application-<def>.css
```

Open the .sprockets-manifest... file and you should see that there are application js and css files with filenames that match the actual **public/assets/** files. This .sprockets-manifest file controls what actually gets included in the HTML head links and scripts when the Rails tags are replaced.

If this is still not working, ensure that the files are accessible by your user running the test (including the manifest). Occasionally lose the .sprockets-manifest file when copying files and in source control as it can appear to be hidden.

Finally, check your file **log/test.log** to see if there are any obvious errors being thrown during the tests.

Answer (score -3):

I found a solution. Perhaps it's not the best one, but it works with me. If anybody find a better approach - let me know, please.

1. Run `rake assets:precompile`. I didn't even set `RAILS_ENV=test`.
2. Modify the `stylesheet_link_tag` method:

> ```
> def stylesheet_link_tag2(*sources)
>   options = sources.extract_options!.stringify_keys
>   path_options = options.extract!('protocol').symbolize_keys
>
>   sources.uniq.map { |source|
>     tag_options = {
>       "rel" => "stylesheet",
>       "media" => "screen",
>       "href" => path_to_stylesheet(source, path_options)[1..-1]
>     }.merge!(options)
>     tag(:link, tag_options)
>   }.join("\n").html_safe
> end
> ```

The idea is to turn the rendered link from this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application-ea5a1efcc44a908543519edabe00e74132151ebedeef3c1601921690d9162b5e.css" data-turbolinks-track="reload" />
```

to this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="assets/application-ea5a1efcc44a908543519edabe00e74132151ebedeef3c1601921690d9162b5e.css" data-turbolinks-track="reload" />
```

eliminating the leading slash in the `href` attribute value (since we don't have a server running but just a saved HTML-page).

3. Replace the code inside the header in `\app\views\layouts\application.html.erb` to:

> ```
> <% if Rails.env.test? %>
>   <%= stylesheet_link_tag2    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
> <% else %>
>   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
> <% end %>
> ```

4. Write a spec like this:

> ```
> require 'rails_helper'
>
> RSpec.describe "testing system", type: :system do
>
>   it "tests..." do
>
>     visit root_path
>
>     click_link 'Home'
>
>     save_and_open_page Rails.root.join( 'public', 'capybara.html' )
>
>   end
>
> end
> ```

5. Add to `.gitignore`:

> `/public/capybara.html`

Do the same thing with the JS-content.

**UPDATE:**

If you don't like modifying `\app\views\layouts\application.html.erb` you can do some monkey patching:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper

alias_method :old_stylesheet_link_tag, :stylesheet_link_tag

def stylesheet_link_tag2(*sources)
  options = sources.extract_options!.stringify_keys
  path_options = options.extract!('protocol').symbolize_keys

  sources.uniq.map { |source|
    tag_options = {
      "rel" => "stylesheet",
      "media" => "screen",
      "href" => path_to_stylesheet(source, path_options)[1..-1]
    }.merge!(options)
    tag(:link, tag_options)
  }.join("\n").html_safe
end  

def stylesheet_link_tag(*sources)

  if Rails.env.test?

    stylesheet_link_tag2(*sources)

  else

    old_stylesheet_link_tag(*sources)

  end

end
```

I usually put such code into `app\helpers\application_helper.rb` and add `include ApplicationHelper` into `app\controllers\application_controller.rb`

**UPDATE 2**
Setting `Capybara.asset_host = "http://localhost:3000/"` as @Thomas Walpole advised doesn't work. That's right - how can it work if `http://localhost:3000/` is **unavailable** (**AFTER** the spec ran)? Of course - when I call `save_and_open_page` the HTML-file opens with a `file://....` address - with no HTTP-server serving it. The attempts to set

```
Capybara.asset_host = "file://#{Rails.root}/public"
```

failed - looks like the **`base`** HTML-tag supports only `http`-adresses - not `file://...` ones. I checked it in Chrome and Firefox.

So my next code proposal is such:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper

alias_method :old_stylesheet_link_tag, :stylesheet_link_tag

def stylesheet_link_tag2(*sources)
  options = sources.extract_options!.stringify_keys
  path_options = options.extract!('protocol').symbolize_keys

  sources.uniq.map { |source|
    tag_options = {
      "rel" => "stylesheet",
      "media" => "screen",
      "href" => "file://#{Rails.root}/public" + path_to_stylesheet(source, path_options)
    }.merge!(options)
    tag(:link, tag_options)
  }.join("\n").html_safe
end  

def stylesheet_link_tag(*sources)

  if Rails.env.test?

    stylesheet_link_tag2(*sources)

  else

    old_stylesheet_link_tag(*sources)

  end

end
```

This eliminates the need to call

```
save_and_open_page Rails.root.join( 'public', 'capybara.html' )
```

instead you can simply call

```
save_and_open_page
```